# If $f$ is continuous from left, it can be written down as $g+h$...

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

Let us have an $f \in M[a,b]$ (this means monotonic functions) function, which is continuous from the left. Since it is monoton, bounded, the limit from left and right side exists. Prove, that in that case, we can write $f=g+h$, where $g$ is continuous and monoton, and where $h$ is a step function.

I have simply no idea, how to prove such statement. I guess, we can use that $g$ to make a function like $f$, but how about that $h$? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas : I think $M[a,b]$ here denotes the set of monotonous functions, but Atvin should precise it in his post.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I left it out.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says a monotonic function has at most countable discontinuities?

Comment: Also, do you allow step functions to have (countably) infinitely many steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : consider the (countable : why ?) set $\mathscr{D} = \{x_1, x_2, ... \}$ of points where $f$ is not continuous. Then these points correspond to some "jumps" of $f$. If $a_i$ is the size of the jump at $h_i$, then consider the step function :
$$h = \sum_{i\geqslant 0} \mathbf{1}_{]x_i, b]}a_i$$
You could now prove that $f-h$ is continuous...

edit : $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$ : $\mathbf{1}_A (x) = 1$ if and only if $x \in A$. Basically, the expression defining $h$ is just a formal way to craft a step function which jumps at every $x_i$, with a jump size of $a_i$".

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thank you!

Comment: What exactly does that "1"$sum_{i\geqslant 0} \mathbf{1}_{[x_i, b]}a_i$ mean on your function?

Comment: Nice argument. I primarily study probability, so I am accustomed to representing "jumps" by indicator functions of singletons, and was wondering where where the step function would come from :)

Comment: Technically, you need $$ \sum_{i\geqslant 0} \mathbf{1}_{(x_i, b]}a_i$$ to get left-continuity - the jumps have to occur after $x_i$, right?

Comment: The set of discontinuities can be infinite, i.e. infinitely many jumps, which add up to a finite number.

Comment: @thomas and MooS : post edited, you're both right !

Comment: You can also write explicitly $$a_i=\lim_{x\to x_i+} f(x) - f(x_i)$$ due to left-continuity.

Comment: A possibly less confusing formula: $$h(x)=f(x)-\sum_{x_i<x} a_i$$

Comment: You even do not need the $x_i$: $h(x) = \sum_{y<x} (\lim_{z \to y+} f(z) -f(y))$

Comment: @MooS Well, we tend to not write sums over uncountable sets, even when the value is zero for all but countable many elements. Way too messy.

Comment: So how do you write down an arbitrary element in a vector space with uncountable (but explicitly known) basis :) ?

Comment: @MooS $x=\sum_{i \in J} e_j a_j$ with $J$ finite ?

Comment: I would be too lazy for this :P. Anyways, sorry for the off-topic. Problem should be solved, I think.

Comment: It should be noted, I wouldn't actually call this a "step function," because to me, a step function needs to be constant on some open intervals. This is doable for some sets of discontinuities, but not for dense sets of discontinuities. But the problem is not true if one uses this definition of "step" function.